# prove the formula and then evalute the sum

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

m,n,r are given non-negative integers, show that

$\sum_{k>=-n}$
${r \choose m+k}$
${s \choose n+k}$
$=$
${r+s \choose r-m+n}$

Then evaluate
$\sum_{k>=0}k$
${r \choose k}$
${s \choose k}$

I tried mathematical induction base on size of r. The base case is when r equals m,but then I found that 2 sides are not equal.
When r equals m,

$LHS = \sum_{k>=0}$
${m \choose m+k}$
${s \choose n+k}$
$=$
${m \choose m+0}$
${s \choose n+0}$
$={m \choose m}{s \choose n}=\frac{s(s-1)...(s-n+1)}{n!}$

$RHS$
$={m+s \choose n}=\frac{(s+m)(s+m-1)...(s+m-n+1)}{n!}$

Comment: @Pieter21 i tried mathematical induction. Base case is when r equals m, then found that i can not prove the base case

Comment: Right, I have shown this and evaluated that. What's next?

Comment: Unfortunately no I cannot "teach you", since you showed nothing of what you know, what you tried to solve this question, and the like. So you effectively *prevented me* (and others) to help you. Note that writing down a full proof below does not count as *helping*, rather as *spoon-feeding*, which is quite different.

Comment: @Did I tried mathematical induction base on size of r. The base case is when r equals m,but then I found that 2 sides are not equal.

Comment: show the steps, we might find an error, of give a new hint.

Comment: and at least show the evaluation, given that the formula is correct.

Comment: Ah, I don't think the sum is filling in $k = 0$, but sum over all possible values of $k$.

Comment: @Pieter21 k can be negative?

Comment: Nope. But it can range from $0$ to $r - m$

Comment: @Pieter21 but when r equals m, the only choice of k is 0 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31904/discussion-between-good-bob-and-pieter21).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first result is false as stated. Take $m=n=1$, $r=s=2$:

$$\binom2{1+0}^2+\binom2{1+1}^2=5\ne 6=\binom{2+2}{2-1+1}\;.$$

To see what it should be, note first that

$$\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{r}{m+k}\binom{s}{n+k}=\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{r}{r-m-k}\binom{s}{n+k}\;.$$

Let $\ell=k+n$, so that $k=\ell-n$; then

$$\binom{r}{r-m-k}\binom{s}{n+k}=\binom{r}{r-m+n-\ell}\binom{s}\ell\;,$$

and [Vandermonde’s identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity) says that

$$\sum_{\ell=0}^{r-m+n}\binom{r}{r-m+n-\ell}\binom{s}\ell=\binom{r+s}{r-m+n}\;.$$

As $\ell$ runs from $0$ to $r-m+n$, $k$ runs from $-n$ to $r-m$. Thus, the correct statement of the first result is

$$\sum_{k\ge -n}\binom{r}{m+k}\binom{s}{n+k}=\binom{r+s}{r-m+n}\;.$$

Since $\binom{s}{n+k}=0$ for $k<-n$, we can in fact simply write this

$$\sum_k\binom{r}{m+k}\binom{s}{n+k}=\binom{r+s}{r-m+n}\;.$$

(Vandermonde’s identity is proved at the link and at several places on this site, in case you’re not already familiar with it.)

For the second problem, note that $k\dbinom{r}k=r\dbinom{r-1}{k-1}$.

Comment: right. I 've edited the question and it turns out to be really simple.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I agree on your calculation.

If the formula would be generally true, it should be true for r = m. Check carefully for typo's, and with this calculation go back to whoever gave you this problem.

(Not a real answer, but an opportunity for discussion, that shouldn't be hidden in the chat discussion.)